# Why my connection in SSH is failing?

Tags: networking, windows-8, ssh, vpn, windows-firewall

I am having trouble with making a connection through SSH Secure client in Windows 8. For making this connecition I am using VPN client and it makes the connection that I want but when I try to make the final step with SSH I obtain the error of the host x.xx.xx.xx is not reacheable. I am not sure but maybe is the firewall of Windows 8, my problem.

Comment: 2 things needed to add to your question. Can you ping the IP? Then also can you confirm that port 22 is open on the server?

Comment: Can you run in command-line: telnet destination_ip port? (telnet might not be enabled on your Windows (recognized as a command), you might need to "telnet client" as a Windows component 1st.)

Comment: @elder elder I run the commandand it says tha the conecction to the host cant be opened in port 22. Connection error

Comment: @Rudolph I can ping withput problems the ip of the VPN client, but the ping of I desired give me the messaje: timeouts and all the packages lost

Comment: Nest step is to flush iptables on the destination's side. try to ssh again right after

Comment: @Rudolph I try netsh for open port, I try the different option to open the port 22 and allow SSH client, and I cant connect. I also try CurrPort and I cant see SSH secure client